# Loading function parameters from a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, eval

I have the following function:

```
def request( url, type, headers, simulate = False, data = {}):
```

I want to be able to load the parameters from a text file and pass them to the function, I tried using evil eval below:

```
if execute_recovery:
    for command in content:
        logger.debug("Executing: "+command)
        try:
            result = eval(utilities.request("{0}").format(command))

            if not result["Success"]:
                continue_recovery = utilities.query_yes_no("Warning: Previous recovery command failed, attempt to continue recovery?\n")
                if not continue_recovery:
                    break
                else:
                    logger.debug("Command executed successfully...")
         except Exception, e:
             logger.debug( "Recovery: Eval Error, %s" % str(e) )
```

Where command would be a line in a text file like:

```
"http://192.168.1.1/accounts/1/users/1",delete,headers,simulate=False,data={}
```

This throws me the following error:

```
'request() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)'
```

So presumably this means that it is interpreting the command as a single string instead of different parameters.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Possibly unrelated: But [don't use mutable objects as default argument value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: It would be better to have the arguments in some more 'friendly' format, like say json which can be safely loaded back into python objects.

Comment: That's actually a very good idea @BurhanKhalid - I'll consider that - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @BurhanKhalid's suggestion, I decided to store the parameters as a json object and load them at run time like so:

Store parameters here:

```
def request( url, type, headers, simulate = False, data = {}):
    if simulate:
        recovery_command = {"url":url, "type" : type, "data" : data}
        recovery.add_command(json.dumps(recovery_command))
        ...
```

Load parameters here:

```
def recovery():
...
    if execute_recovery:
        for command in content:
            logger.debug("Executing: "+command)
            try:

                recovery_command = json.loads(command)

                result = utilities.request(url = recovery_command["url"], type = recovery_command["type"], headers = headers, simulate = False, data = recovery_command["data"])

                if not result["Success"]:
                    continue_recovery = utilities.query_yes_no("Warning: Previous recovery command failed, attempt to continue recovery?\n")
                    if not continue_recovery:
                        break
                else:
                    logger.debug("Command executed successfully...")
            except Exception, e:
                logger.debug( "Recovery: Eval Error, %s" % str(e) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand what you are trying to do there with eval or format. For one thing, you've put `eval` around the call to `request` itself, so it will evaluate the return value rather than call it with some dynamic value.

But you don't need eval at all. You just need to pass the arguments using the `*` and `**` operators:

```
args = []
kwargs = {}
for arg in command.split(','):
    if '=' in arg:
        k, v = arg.split('=')
        kwargs[k] = ast.literal_eval(v)
    else:
        args.append(arg)
result = utilities.request(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: If I have a case where the command would look like `"http://192.168.1.1/accounts/1/users/",post,headers,simulate=False,data={username:"john",age:"30"}`, would this solution still work?

Comment: Hmm, probably not. You could use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the kwarg value in that case, see my edit.